# Javascript styling element

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a function that will set css params to element. I have the following code:

```
var css = function(k, l){
    for(key in l){
        k.style.key = l[key];
    }
}
```

But it is not working. I think it's because of the key variable. Is there some way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, declare `key` as var in order to make it strict, and then, you have to access the property of `style` with brackets:

```
var css = function (k, l) {
    for (var key in l) {
        k.style[key] = l[key];
    }
}
```